# Compiling a JNI file with c++ postgresql in command prompt getting fatal error

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpqxx

Command executed:

```
g++ -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2\include\win32" -I"C:\Program Files\libpqxx\include\pqxx" -shared -o hello.dll HelloJNI.cpp
```

pqxx file dir - `C:\Program Files\libpqxx\include`

I have included the path with `-I` .

I am using C++ for the backend connection for my Java program using JNI and unable to compile the cpp file, getting error as:

```
HelloJNI.cpp:4:10: fatal error: pqxx/pqxx: No such file or director
    4 | #include <pqxx/pqxx>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

**The executed code is:**

```
#include <jni.h>       // JNI header provided by JDK
#include <iostream>    // C++ standard IO header
#include "HelloJNI.h"  // Generated
#include <pqxx/pqxx>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Implementation of the native method sayHello()
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) 
{
     try
    {
        std::string connectionString = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password =caNarain@2002";

        pqxx::connection connectionObject(connectionString.c_str());

        pqxx::work worker(connectionObject);

        pqxx::result response = worker.exec("SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY BOOK_ID");

        for (size_t i = 0; i < response.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << response[i][0] << " " << response[i][1] << " " << response[i][2] << " " << response[i][3] << " " << response[i][4] << " " << response[i][5] << std::endl;
        }

        return;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You should use `C:\Program Files\libpqxx\include` as include path, without `pqxx` at the end, because otherwise g++ will search the include file `C:\Program Files\libpqxx\include\pqxx\pqxx\pqxx`

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir, But while trying that I am getting more errors that I can't able to figure it out

Comment: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\canar\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1lOM3L.o:HelloJNI.cpp:(.text+0x104): undefined reference to `pqxx::result::operator[](int) const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\canar\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1lOM3L.o:HelloJNI.cpp:(.text+0x120): undefined reference to `pqxx::row::operator[](int) const'


undefined reference to `pqxx::transaction_base::do_abort()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use JNI/C++ instead of  plain JDBC?

Comment: It was a task I have to make the backend with c++ and UI with Java to build a CLI application.

Comment: Yes but you aren't doing that. You are using Java at the backend with JNI code. It's pontless. Just use JDBC directly from Java, if what you're doing is already permissible.

Comment: No I'm just trying to retrieve the data from the c program using JNI to java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compile the file in visual studio.

Add the paths to the respective fields like additional include directories, linker files in the property.

conclude the `JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj)`

inside a `int main()` method to compile since visual studio cannot compile the files without main method.

you can follow same as cmdline if your program doesn't have postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using -I"C:\Program Files\libpqxx\include\pqxx"
The #include should not be

```
<pqxx/pqxx>
```

You can try -I"C:\Program Files\libpqxx\include" to make the search path consistent.

Comment: Without including the header I can't able to use the libraries of postgresql like work, commit, connection etc

Comment: I just found your comments in the comment part.  Looks like you are using the mingw32 g++ to compile.  
BTW,  how do you compile the: libpqxx?  Is it also using the mingw32 compiling? 
My experience is just to use libpq (pure C) for jni.  It's more stable and flexible to get it work.

Comment: Actually my project is in cpp that's why I'm using g++ for compiling

Comment: thanks.  So you are using the same compiler to compile the libpqxx or you just refer to the 3rdpart compiled library of libpqxx?

Comment: It is compiling fine in visual studio as a pure cpp project while coming to JNI I can't use visual studio, I am trying to compile in command prompt with mingw

Comment: It should be able to use visual studio to compile.  If not, please double check the proper version of jvm dll which is supported in studio to link. 
The better is to not use different compiler to do the jni work.
Or the other way is try to use mingw32 to compile libpqxx and the jni code both.

Comment: While compiling in Visual studio I am getting error in the exe file

Comment: Hello Sean thank you for helping me I've found what was the error. A main method was missing in the code. Visual studio cannot compile a program without main

Comment: Good news for that.